# Assigning max value of long to long type throws an exception

Tags: java, long-integer

The first line of code does not throw an exception, but the second line, which assigns the max value of long throws a RuntimeException. Can someone clarify this confusion? Thank you.

```
long val1 = Long.MAX_VALUE;
long val2 = 9223372036854775807;
```

Comment: In java by default number literal's are treated as integer. to Specify long you must add l or L. but In this case you should get compilation exception, because `The literal 9223372036854775807 of type int is out of range`, not run-time .

Answer (score 6):

change it to

```
long val2 = 9223372036854775807L;
```

without the L, it is treated as an int literal, and this number is too high for an int.

Answer (score 4):

You're using **integer literal**, you need **long literal**:

```
long val2 = 9223372036854775807L;
```

*You need add 'l' or 'L' to the end of integer literal to get long literal.*

```
long a = 100; // integer literal, good - 'L' adding compiler
long b = 100L; // long literal, good
long c = 10000000000; // integer literal, bad - too large
long d = 10000000000L; // long literal, good
```

You may read about literals in [Oracle Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Answer (score 4):

When you type in a number in Java, the compiler automatically reads it as an integer, which is why when you type in (long) 9223372036854775807 (not in integer's range) it will complain that 9223372036854775807 is not an integer.

To make it shut up, You have to specify 9223372036854775807L with an **L** after, to tell the compiler that the number is a **long literal**.

More info can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10) where Integer Literals are discussed in Java documentation.

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII
>   letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1).